# Apache2 gzip not working?

Tags: server, apache2, amazon-ec2, aws, .htaccess

I've done almost everything on the internet to `gzip` my content. It does not seem to work. I've done so much that I can't possibly put everything I've tried here, so here's some of the things I've tried:

I've tried adding this into my `.htaccess` and I also tried adding it into my `apache2.conf` and restarting apache.

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
  # Compress HTML, CSS, JavaScript, Text, XML and fonts
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml

  # Remove browser bugs (only needed for really old browsers)
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
  BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
  BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
  Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>
```

They both don't work. I'm on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu server with Apache.

Comment: When you say 'gzip my content', I assume you mean compressing files as they are served from the webserver?

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere Yes, you're right.

Comment: Anyone know anything about this?

Comment: did you check the apache module deflate is enabled

Comment: @TamilSelvan Yes, mod deflate and gzip are enabled

Comment: Can you share with us the complete version of apache?

Comment: @AhmadMushtaq Apache/2.4.7

Comment: How are you testing to confirm that it isn't working?

Comment: @Brian Multiple sites. GTMetrix, top 5 results of https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=gzip+test&oq=gzip+test&gs_l=hp.3..0l10.354.1104.0.1143.10.9.0.0.0.0.119.616.2j4.6.0....0...1c.1.64.hp..4.5.518.0..0i131.IK1AnObrT64

Comment: @edwardjiang7 I know it sounds common sense but is Apache reading your .htaccess? Test your configuration by putting random strings into your .htaccess file and see if the server gives you a 401 error.

Comment: @AhmadMushtaq Yes, .htaccess works. I've had a few redirects and other things in there for a while now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer... finally!

It was in this code that was something like this:

```
SetEnvIfExpr no-gzip
```

It was in my apache2.conf file. Once I removed that code, it worked!

Answer (score 0):

#### Apache2 say:

> *One further directive **AddOutputFilterByType** is still supported, but deprecated. Use dynamic configuration instead.*

First I thought that better to use ***AddOutputFilter*** directive.

---

However solution found at [How to enable gzip compression on Apache](https://web.archive.org/web/20170504161741/http://howtounix.info/howto/Apache-gzip-compression-with-mod_deflate) show enough anew way to configure `mod_deflate`.

Lookalike:

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
 AddType application/x-javascript .js
 AddType text/css .css
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
  <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
   SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:rar|zip)$ no-gzip dont-vary
   SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpg|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
   SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:avi|mov|mp4)$ no-gzip dont-vary
   SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.mp3$ no-gzip dont-vary
  </IfModule>
 <IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
 </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Read subj for a varies.

---

Example of Apache 1.3 `mod_gzip` module mean just:

```
  <ifModule mod_gzip.c>
    mod_gzip_on Yes
    mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
    mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
    mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
    mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
    mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
  </ifModule>
```

[look more / found here](https://varvy.com/pagespeed/enable-compression.html)

And my humble opinion that the part about **really old browsers** is not very reliable part of your `.htaccess` …

Comment: No sorry, it says gzip is still not enabled.

Comment: can you show your response headers?

Comment: If you're wondering about the "Accept-Encoding", this is what it says: Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate